# How can I get text in a list item when we click it in android?

Tags: android-listview

Here is my code snippet :

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
   super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "clicked " + 
     position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this link:

```
ArrayList<String> list;
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
{

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                    long arg3) 
{
                ArrayList<String> newList=new ArrayList<String>();
                newList=list.get(position);//Text will be featch according to the position
                String name=newList.get(0).toString(); 
    }
}
```